# We shall be like him because we shall see him as he is?

Tags: 1-john

1 John 3:2:

> Ἀγαπητοί νῦν τέκνα θεοῦ ἐσμεν, καὶ οὔπω ἐφανερώθη τί ἐσόμεθα. οἴδαμεν ὅτι ἐὰν φανερωθῇ, ὅμοιοι αὐτῷ ἐσόμεθα, ὅτι ὀψόμεθα αὐτὸν, καθώς ἐστιν. ([UBS5](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/greek-new-testament-ubs-gnt5/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/ch/bd5682d9560f044e1ce13aa2cd4c2e0f/?tx_buhbibelmodul_bibletext%5Bscripture%5D=1+john+3))
>
> Beloved, we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet appeared; but we know that when he appears we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is. ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/1%20John%203/))

This last part is not intuitive to me: seeing him (as he is) causes us to be like him? I’m trying to figure out if this followed more naturally for the original audience.

Is this a Jewish notion? Or a Greek notion? Is there evidence of this way of thinking in other (biblical<sup>1</sup> or extra-biblical) texts? Or is there a timeless logical sequence here that I’m just missing?

---

<sup>1. It seems like there’s something of this same concept behind 2 Cor 3:18 (*with unveiled face, beholding the glory of the Lord, [we] are being transformed into the same image…*), although there the cause and effect relationship (beholding → being transformed) isn’t explicit, and the meaning of κατοπτριζόμενοι is perhaps more nuanced than ὀψόμεθα.</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The context supports a causative understanding of the phrase "...we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is", and the context is crucial to the nuance of correct interpretation too.

> <sup>3:1</sup>See what kind of love the Father has given to us, that we should be called children of God; and so we are. ***The reason why the world does not know us is that it did not know him***. <sup>2</sup>Beloved, we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet appeared; but we know that when he appears we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is. <sup>3</sup>***And everyone who thus hopes in him purifies himself*** as he is pure. <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/1john3.1-3)</sub></sub>

- **Unrighteousness flows from not knowing the Son<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>**

  The impurity of the world evidenced by the world's response to the children of God is *caused* by the world's lack of knowledge of the Son.
- **'Seeing' in verse 2 is a more intense form of 'knowing' in verse 1**

  'Seeing' should not be understood literally as visual, rather it is in polar opposition to the lack of knowledge of the world. John is drawing a picture of three tiers:

  1. The 'world', who do not know
  2. The 'children', who know in part ("...we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet appeared...")
  3. The perfected 'children', who know/see him 'as he is'
- **The hope of knowing him more causes purification**

  Verse 3 explains the mechanics of how those who 'know' the Son attain the level of knowledge where ultimately they see him as he is - it is a virtuous circle of increasing knowledge fed by the desire to attain more perfect knowledge of him.

#### Conclusion:

The logic of v1-3 is: ***those who know him desire to know him more, which causes their purity to converge with his***. This process reaches conclusion when he is known so well that he is seen "as he is" - which evidences the attainment of purity comparable with his own. It is the knowledge of the Son that leads to purity, in a self-fulfilling fashion, via ever increasing knowledge of him.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *or possibly the Father - see chapter 2:18-29*</sub>

Comment: That's a really good point that v.3 uses the same sort of logic, and your conclusion sums it up well. I was just being dense.

Comment: @Jack I think this vs was trad. understood by some traditions to mean 'changed in the twinkling of an eye' as in our 'bodies will be changed' for those who are 'alive and remain'. This is the mortal putting on immortality, when we see Him as He is (immortal and glorified) we will immediately be changed into immortality and glorified also, sharing in His Glory, as it was "in the beginning,....they were clothed with the Glory of God."@SUSAN

Comment: @Jack-your answer above is beautiful, meat-y, rich, and overflowing with spiritual food.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those who say it is about our immortal body. I add: about our body that will be like Jesus' body that He had when He rose from the dead, which will happen when we see Him at His return. This is John writing, and this is consistent with his other writings on this subject. In his gospel, he quotes Jesus saying in 5:28 Do not marvel at this, for an hour is coming when all who are in the tombs will hear his voice 29 and come out" and in 11:25 "Whoever believes in me, though he die, yet shall he live, 26 and everyone who lives and believes in me shall never die.", immediately before He raises Lazarus from the dead, and not too long before He Himself will be raised with His glorified body which can no longer die, in which He will ascend back to heaven. Then in Revelation John writes about the 2nd coming of Christ and the resurrections of the dead that are associated with that. And now here in 1 John he is telling us that we have not yet seen what we will be after that day, but we do know that on that day, when He appears(returns?), we will then be like Him. Until then, if we die before His return, our spirits will be in paradise, but our bodies sleep and await their glorification and being reunited with our spirits, just as happened with His body for 3 days before His glorified body rose(we will be like Him!). I think all of that would be consistent with John's other writings on the resurrection of the body. Also, consistent with Paul's writings such as 1 Corinthians 15:51 "Behold, I tell you a mystery, we will not all sleep, but we will all be changed, in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised imperishable, and we will be changed...". On that day we will see exactly what we shall be, when we see Him at His return. See also Roman's 8:11"If the spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he who raised Christ Jesus fro the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His spirit who dwells in you", and of course Thessalonians 4:13-18 and Philippians 3:1, and others. When Jesus appears(returns), then we(whether we sleep or live at that time) will see what it is that we will become. Come soon, Lord Jesus!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack exchange. Please see the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how BH.SE is a bit different from other websites. If you should have further questions, please see the [help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) of the site for guidance. This question has been marked as answered, so we ask that any additional answers be thoroughly explained with sources and demonstrate a clear progression of thought. Thank you for sharing your thoughts, we hope to see you around the site more.

Answer (score 0):

WE. SHALL BE LIKE HIM BECAUSE WE SHALL SEE HIM AS HE REALLY IS.

I agree...it isn’t just or at all about physical SEEING.
It’s about deep deep down KNOWING....and not gnostic knowing either.
...not info.... not even wisdom....but knowing in the deepest fashion.
.....PERCEIVE comes to mind.
So, we shall REALLY SEE....or REALLY KNOW, and what we see AND KNOW,
is that we are LIKE HIM....that is the meaning of the earlier statement........we are children of God now,.....where we ARE TO BE
has not yet been revealed...but then IT WILL BE.
...WE WILL BE LIKE HIM.....WE SHALL KNOW AS WE ARE KNOWN....WE WILL BE ON A PARR.....WE SHALL LOVE AS WE ARE LOVED.....I suppose we could go on.......THIS IS THE NEW CREATION...THIS IS TRUE HOLINESSS....THIS IS PARADISE RESTORED........etc.......

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom, left) as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Using capitals as emphasis is discouraged as it offends some people who regard it as 'shouting'. It is better to use italics to emphasise.

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful for the replies.
The problems we have are because of words.
They get in the way.

Seeing God face to face does imply a sameness
in the two beings....face to face. There is a
sense of equality. It also implies a sense of mutual recognition
of mutuality or at least not a great deal of
negativity flowing. In other words ( words again ),
“ I am extremely pleased to see you “ from both sides.
The title of the 60s book...Mr God, this is Anna...comes to mind.
Finally, there is a sharing of Love which communicates everything.
Maybe it is much more simple and natural when the moment arrives.
Of course it will be.
“ Blessed are the pure in heart
For they shall see our God.“
The word “ see “ here means something far deeper than
Eyesight. It is nearer to “ knowing “ or “ experiencing “.
.....allowing ourselves to be “ drawn into “ something...
which in this context is God.
....in fact, drawn into “ the holy “, the Mysterium , tremendans et fascinans .” Rudolph Otto.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your answer.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Are you able to support your ideas with some references or Bible verses?

Comment: ”Blessed are the pure in heart, for they will see God”— this connection that you make with the Beatitudes is especially insightful and encapsulates, in my opinion, the message of this epistle, which begins with a focus on the law (1 Jn:4-10), then proceeds to love (1 Jn:11-17), and ends with the heart (1 Jn:18-22). As children of God, we are shown to be in the process of _becoming_ and of learning how to be more like Jesus, He whose heart is above all most pure.

Answer (score 0):

I’m with Susan on this one. I can’t tell you how many times i’ve read this verse and I just couldn’t manage to “get it.” But I think I have it now. The Bible talks about not being able to see God’s *full* glory and live, even for angels that cover their faces with their extra pair of wings (and their feet with the other extra pair - 6 total).  We can’t see Jesus’s full glory without not just having *some* kind of new body, but one that is supremely fitted and preserved by the Holy Spirit for beholding Christ’s absolutely unveilled full glory without being destroyed. This will require us to be as much like Christ as possible - without being deity, obviously.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

**We shall be like him because we shall see him as he is?**

1 John 3:2 NET

> 2 Dear friends, we are God’s children now, and what we will be[a] has
> not yet been ***revealed.*** We know that whenever it is revealed we
> will be like him because we will see him just as he is.

1 John 3:2: ESV

> Beloved, we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet
> appeared, but we know that when he appears we shall be like him
> because we shall see him as he is.

**What has been revealed to the Annointed Christians/Holy ones.**

What has not yet been revealed to them is what they shall be like when they are resurrected to heaven with spirit bodies. (Phil 3:20-21)

Philippians 3:20-21 NET

> 20 But our citizenship is in heaven—and we also eagerly await a savior
> from there, the Lord Jesus Christ, 21 who will transform these humble
> bodies of ours into the likeness of his glorious body by means of that
> power by which he is able to subject all things to himself.

What has been revealed to them is that they shall be like him, shall see him just as he is, that is "the Spirit".

2 Corinthians 3:17-18 NET

> 17 Now the Lord is the Spirit, and where the Spirit of the Lord is
> present, there is freedom. 18 And we all, with unveiled faces
> reflecting the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same
> image from one degree of glory to another, **which is from the Lord, who
> is the Spirit.**

Answer (score -4):

The first application that came to mind is how this could apply to RCatholic doctrine. Since Jesus is God, and this verse does say we shall see Him, as He is,...this would apply to the RC beatific vision, seeing God Face to Face. (In RC doctrine this means the believer is 'in heaven', and therefore is not in purgatory, so they 'made it'.

In your question you phrase, 'shall be like Him, because of seeing Him as He is', implying that the 'being like Him' is because of 'seeing Him as He is',..however, I do not believe the verse is saying, exactly what you are implying.

I believe the verse is making a statement, recording 'how things shall be, concerning us'.*

'We shall be like him', is stated in other places in the NT, where our new bodies are written about, 'our mortality putting on immortality'. our 'corruption putting on incorruption', and all of the other places that state we will no longer cry, be in pain, have any sickness, or even die, and all sorrow will be gone.

By saying this I am meaning that the 'shall be like Him' may refer to our new body being exactly like His resurrected and then glorified body, BECAUSE Jesus, although God, is still a human man INSIDE the Godhead. (think, ponder this, you will get my meaning)

Some bible references for this are as follows,..

- 2 Cor 5:1-3,  2 Pet 1:13-14
- > God, through Christ, will deliver us from this present "body of death" (which is the sinful nature plus how these present bodies were plunged into the fall, and how the fall has effected them).  Rom 7:20-25
- > God has prepared us for the purpose of being clothed with our heavenly body.  2 Cor 5:4-5
- > Although we do not know exactly what our new bodies will be like, we know that they will be like Jesus' glorious resurrected body.  1 John 3:2-3
- > Our new bodies will be like Christ's glorious body.  Phil 3:20-21, Rom 8:28-30,  Ps 17:15,  Rom 6:5-8, 1 Cor 15:49,  2 Cor 3:17-18

Following along the RC doctrine line of thinking about this question,
an RC scholar might say that this verse supports RC doctrine, the beatific vision, including purgatorial cleansing being alluded to by the 'seeing Him as He is', it is the seeing Him as He is that may cause the purgatorial cleansing,..ie some RC's believe Purgatory could be short, 'in the twinkling of an eye', the 'seeing God' cleanses the last vestiges of 'the fall' right out of us,...making us ready for Heaven.

Protestants would not generally interpret this like I have written above, because they generally do not agree that there is a Purgatory, although Luther himself still believed in it, post RC church, although Protestant scripture says nothing about it, according to Protestants.

KJV is a translation that comes directly from the original, so I will quote it here.

> 1 John 3:2 King James Version (KJV)
>
> Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.

In KJV the 'because' is the word 'for', but the word is called a conjunction,... connective, and may not mean 'because', exactly, or, it may (See [Strong's G3754 ὅτι](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=KJV&strongs=G3754)).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Regarding `...implying that the 'being like Him' is because of 'seeing Him as He is',..however, I do not believe the verse is saying, exactly what you are implying.`: Are you questioning the translation? It seems pretty clear in the English I provided. I asked [another question about translation of this verse](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13698/3555) because there's a lot unclear here, but this apparently causal relationship seems clear to me.

Comment: @Susan - I think this vs. in many traditions was always thought to be about getting an immortal body. 'we will be like him '-changed in the twinkling of an eye' bible quote. when we see him 2nd advent He will be glorified as well, so we may have His Glory bk on us, lost at the time of the fall in the garden, this would be physically seen glory as opposed to the spiritual glory we have now.